# постраничный вывод товаров php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Вечер добрый!
Не могу разобраться, как сделать так, чтобы отображались изображения, а не только их имена, которые хранятся в бд.

```
<?php
function link_bar($page, $pages_count)
{
for ($j = 1; $j <= $pages_count; $j++)
{
// Вывод ссылки
if ($j == $page) {
echo ' <a style="color: #808000;" ><b>'.$j.'</b></a> ';
} else {
echo ' <a style="color: #808000;" href='.$_SERVER['php_self'].'?page='.$j.'>'.$j.'</a> ';
}
// Выводим разделитель после ссылки, кроме последней
// например, вставить "|" между ссылками
if ($j != $pages_count) echo ' ';
}
return true;
} // Конец функции

// Подключение к базе данных

// Подготовка к постраничному выводу
$perpage = 3; // Количество отображаемых данных из БД

if (empty(@$_GET['page']) || ($_GET['page'] <= 0)) {
$page = 1;
} else {
$page = (int) $_GET['page']; // Считывание текущей страницы
}
// Общее количество информации
$count = mysql_numrows(mysql_query('SELECT name_products, picture_products FROM products')) or die('error! Записей не найдено!');
$pages_count = ceil($count / $perpage); // Количество страниц

// Если номер страницы оказался больше количества страниц
if ($page > $pages_count) $page = $pages_count;
$start_pos = ($page - 1) * $perpage; // Начальная позиция, для запроса к БД

// Вызов функции, для вывода ссылок на экран
link_bar($page, $pages_count);

// Вывод информации из базы данных
$result = mysql_query('select name_products, picture_products from products limit '.$start_pos.', '.$perpage) or die('error!');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo '<p>'.$row['name_products'].'</p>';
echo '<p>'.$row['picture_products'].'</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Если название изображения в переменной `$row['picture_products']` полностью совпадает с адресом этого изображения, то нужно просто поместить `$row['picture_products']` в атрибут `src` тега `<img />`. Для этого просто замените эту строку: `echo '<p>'.$row['picture_products'].'</p>';` на эту: `echo '<p><img src="'. $row['picture_products'] .'" alt="'. $row['picture_products'] .'" /></p>';`

Comment: В переменной хранится только название, например: 1.jpg

Comment: Всё, разобрался. Спасибо большое

Comment: Единственное, не получается задать параметры изображения (высоту и ширину)

Comment: параметры изображения можно задать с помощью соответствующих атрибутов: __[Тег <img>](http://htmlbook.ru/html/img)__

Comment: Я знаю, просто не понимаю, может ставлю не туда.
echo 
          '<th><p><img src="images/'. $files['picture_products'] .'" widht="200" height="200"  alt="'. $files['picture_products'] .'"></p></th>';